# Change a localized InfoPlist.strings using an Xcode target

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, build-process, plist

Here's an obscure problem. I'm using an InfoPlist.strings to localize my app name. It's only got one value: `CFBundleDisplayName = "Mon App"`. The strings file is localized (putting it in a directory for that localization).

I've just made an extra target, where I change things like the non-localized app name (different `Info.plist`s), and the icon. I'm also changing the Default.png using a run script build phase (copying different files depending on the app type I'm building).

I've tried using the script to copy different versions of my InfoPlist.strings, but I couldn't make it work. Here's what I used:

```
if($TARGET_NAME == "MonApp")then
cp fr.lproj/MonApp_InfoPlist.strings fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
endif
```

I've seen a post suggesting [wincent strings util](http://wincent.com/a/products/wincent-strings-util/) for processing strings, but wanted to see if there's an easy way to do this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do this.

If you have fr.lprog/InfoPlist.strings and en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings in your project, you should see just one InfoPlist.strings entry, with two subitems fr and en.  If you drag and drop the InfoPlist.strings file into a Copy Bundle Resources build phase, all localized versions will be copied into the appropriate .lproj files at build time.  You don't need to create a separate target or write a script to do this; the right thing happens.